# Get seller items count by various criteria

Tags: api, ebay-api

I want to retrieve the total number of items of a seller, by various aspects like number of all items, number of active items, number of sold items, number of returned items, etc. I just need the count, not the complete item details. Couldn't find any good API for that.

[GetMyeBaySelling](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getmyebayselling.html) does return the items by various aspects but it returns the complete item details. I can't find any option to 'exclude' item details from the results, so that only pagination is returned that gives the total count.

What other method in the eBay API can I use to achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the number of items only you can add an OutputSelector to the GetMyeBaySelling call. For you purpose `<OutputSelector>TotalNumberOfEntries</OutputSelector>` would be sufficient. But you are able to add more OutputSelectors according to your needs. For most of the eBay Trading API calls the OutputSelector field is available.

I've created an example for the GetMyeBaySelling call in our [API playground](https://sdk.intradesys.com/s/f0935e4cd5920aa6c7c996a5ee53a70f) with the OutputSelectors "TotalNumberOfEntries" and "Summary". Feel free to modify the call and see the result directly in the response area. For example if you don't need the Summary just remove the field from the request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I couldn't respond earlier, because I had started working on something else. Now, I have got the time to test it. But I  am unable to get the desired result.

I have tried the `<OutputSelector>` but response still include all other details of the item. I tried to use all possible values like `TotalNumberOfEntries`,`ActiveList.PaginationResult`,`ActiveList.PaginationResult.TotalNumberOfEntries` etc but other unneeded details are still there. I even used the exact same soap xml that you have in the API Playground, but nothing seems to be working. Any idea?

Comment: <OutputSelector>TotalNumberOfEntries</OutputSelector> is as tidy as you will be able to get the results. you need to then parse the xml response with something like SimpleXML e.g. for a tally of unsold, i use $xml->UnsoldList->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfEntries;

Comment: @mico that API playground is amazing! never stumbled across it before, what a resource!